# How to set 'ColumnWidth' using ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")?

Tags: javascript, activexobject

I'm using ActiveXObject("Excel.Application") to export html table to Exel in IE Explorer,here is my code:

```
var curTbl = document.getElementById(tableId);
var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
var xlsheet = oWB.Worksheets(1);
var sel = document.body.createTextRange();
sel.moveToElementText(curTbl);
sel.execCommand("Copy");
xlsheet.Paste();
var fname = oXL.Application.GetSaveAsFilename(name+".xls", "Excel Spreadsheets (*.xls), *.xls");
oWB.SaveAs(fname);
oWB.Close(savechanges = false);
oXL.Quit();
oXL = null;
```

I searched this and get this.

```
xlsheet.ActiveSheet.Columns(startcol+":"+endcol).ColumnWidth = 22;
```

But it didn't work and 'ActiveSheet' is undifined.Help ,thank you.

Comment: Try as xlsheet.Columns(startcol+":"+endcol).ColumnWidth = 22;

Comment: It also didn't work,and cause exception.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,i find an answer.Use

```
xlsheet.columns.AutoFit();
```

or

```
var myRange = xlsheet.Range(xlsheet.Cells(2, 1), xlsheet.Cells(2, 7));
myRange.Columns.AutoFit();
myRange.Rows.AutoFit();
```